# Compute the area under a line in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with +1000 rows and I would compute the area under the line of each row. For example, suppose I have a dataset like this:

```
df<-rbind(c(0, 2, 0, 3, 0),
          c(2, 2, 0, 1, 0))
```

For the first row, I would compute the area under the line in this figure:
[image]

which would be

```
> 2*2/2+2*3/2
[1] 5
```

And for the second row, it would be

```
> 1*2+1*2/2+2*1/2
[1] 4
```

[image]

I'm wondering whether there is an easy way to realize it in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `pracma` package

```
library(pracma)
trapz(df[1,])
```

Comment: Thanks @Fedorenko Kristina. It's much helpful.